# Geofencing UILocalNotification not working properly swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am facing a strange problem with local notification in swift.
I am presenting local notification like this

```
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        var body = "Hi Krishna";
        if(region.identifier == "entry1") {
            body += " Welcome";
        } else {
            body += " Bye! Bye!";
        }
        notification.alertBody = body
        notification.soundName = "Default";

        notification.userInfo = ["id": "id"];

        notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

and how I am handling launch options in my appdelegate

```
    if(launchOptions != nil) {
        window?.rootViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor();
        if let notification = launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification {
            window?.rootViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
            if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
                window?.rootViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
                if let id = userInfo["id"] as? String {
                    window?.rootViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

for debugging purpose I am changing the background color of the view.
when I tap to the notification I get the cyan color that means below line is failing

```
launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification
```

because I set cyan color right above this line.
so I am not getting why this is not castable to UILocalNotification?
can somebody help me to get rid from this issue?+

one more thing actually if I am doing it normally its working but I am using geofencing and I am scheduling notification from

```
locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion)
```

In this case its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `application(_:didReceiveLocalNotification:)` (which gives you the notification directly) in your AppDelegate and handle the notification there.

More: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification:

Comment: didReceiveLocalNotification is only called if your app is active

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to cast like this:

```
if let notification:UILocalNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification {
        //do stuff with notification
}
```